# Converting rows into columns based on the values in the rows, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

This is the table I am working with. I want to convert `reservation` into separate columns.

[image]

I want it to be transformed into something like this. I have been trying to do this using `reshape2` and `dplyr`'s `separate` but I didn't find a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(reservation_main = str_split(reservation,'_' ,simplify = T)[1],
         reservation_no = paste0('_',str_split(reservation,'_' ,simplify = T)[2])) %>%
  select(id, response_id, reservation_main, reservation_no) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = reservation_no, values_from = response_id)


     id reservation_main  `_1`  `_2`  `_3`
  <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 31100 A                    1     1     0
2 31100 B                    1     1     0
3 31100 C                    1     0     0
```

Comment: Wow. This worked like charm. Just curious, I am a budding data analyst. How did you manage to think in this particular way? Any tips you'd give me? Or do you have blog posts or something I can read. Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @NirshadNijam This kind of manipulation can be done by `reshape2::` `melt` <-> `dcast` or `tidyr::` `pivot_longer` <-> `pivot_wider`. Site that I'm using is not in english, so it might be helpful searching `melt in r` or `pivot_longer in r` or etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since `reservation` is in a consistent format, we can use the `_` to separate into two columns. Then, we can convert the `response` to 0 and 1. Then, I drop `response_id`. Finally, I pivot to the wide format. I'm assuming that you don't want the `_` before the numbers in the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(reservation, c("reservation", "number"), sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(response = ifelse(response == "yes", 1, 0)) %>%
  select(-response_id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "number", values_from = "response")
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id reservation   `1`   `2`   `3`
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 31100 A               1     1     0
2 31100 B               1     1     0
```

If you do want to keep the `_` in front of the numbers for the columns, then we could adjust the regex in `separate`.

```
df %>%
  separate(reservation, c("reservation", "number"), sep = "(?=\\_)") %>%
  mutate(response = ifelse(response == "yes", 1, 0)) %>%
  select(-response_id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "number", values_from = "response")

# A tibble: 2 × 5
     id reservation  `_1`  `_2`  `_3`
  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 31100 A               1     1     0
2 31100 B               1     1     0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    id = c(31100, 31100, 31100, 31100, 31100, 31100),
    reservation = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "B_3"),
    response = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"),
    response_id = c(1,
                    1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-6L)
)
```